# Adding the value of variable to te next variable in a loop

Tags: excel, foreach, vba

I need a help in a code I wrote, this code is going through each cell in column E and if it finds a word "Total" in the column it assigns the variable `ChargebleHours` the value of cell in F column of same row the code is:

```
Sub ChargeableHours()
DIM E as Range,F as Range, r as Range
SET E = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("E:E"))
FOR Each r IN E
   If Left(r.Text,5) = "Total" Then
      ChargebleHours = Cells(r.Row,"F").Value
   End If
Next r
EndSub
```

Now I am having trouble in implementing second loop where it stores the value of variable `ChargebleHours` it previously found and adds to the next value it finds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you mean something like this:

```
ChargebleHours = ChargebleHours + Cells(r.Row,"F").Value
```

or this:

```
Cells(r.Row,"E").Value = Cells(r.Row,"E").Value + ChargebleHours
```